# Create dropdown from one-to-many relationship with AngularJS and Web API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have 2 tables in my database: People and Payband. I'll give a reduced version of the relationship below:

**dbo.People**

```
PersonId : int (PK)
FirstName : string
MiddleInitial: string
LastName : string
DateOfBirth: datetime
PaybandId : int (FK)
```

**dbo.Paybands**

```
Id : int (PK)
Name : string
```

So I've created an ASP.NET Web API service for my backend and using HTML/CSS and AngularJS for my front-end. I'm able to pull, display and edit data no problem. Here's an image of what my form looks like:

[image]

I'm able to get the current Payband value that's assigned to a person, the only problem is that I'm unable to get all the other Payband values and display them in the HTML dropdown so that you can easily change the payband for any given person. I'm at a loss for how to achieve what I'm trying to do, so if someone can help me with this, I'd really appreciate it. Thank you in advance and if you have any other questions, please ask away.

Also, here's my AngularJS controller (yes, I'm currently hardcoding the Id of the person for testing):

```
angular
.module("personnelService")
.controller("PersonnelEditCtrl",
             PersonnelEditCtrl);

function PersonnelEditCtrl(personnelResource) {
var vm = this;
vm.person = {};
vm.message = '';

personnelResource.get({ id: 2 },
    function (data) {
        vm.person = data;
        vm.person.dob = new Date(vm.person.dob);
        vm.originalPerson = angular.copy(data);
    });

if (vm.person && vm.person.personId) {
    vm.title = "Edit: " + vm.person.firstName + " " + vm.person.lastName;
}
else {
    vm.title = "New Person";
}

vm.submit = function () {
    vm.message = '';
    if (vm.person.personId) {
        vm.person.$update({ id: vm.person.personId },
            function (data) {
                vm.message = '... Save Complete';
            })
    }
    else {
        vm.person.$save(
            function (data) {
                vm.originalPerson = angular.copy(data);
                vm.message = '... Save Complete';
            })
    }
};

vm.cancel = function (editForm) {
    editForm.$setPristine();
    vm.person = angular.copy(vm.originalPerson);
    vm.message = "";
};
```

}

Comment: Really not clear what specific problem is. You need an api endpoint to get all available Paybands and a $resource or $http to get them

Comment: My issue, I thought, was pretty clear. I'm sorry if it wasn't. I don't know how to properly populate a dropdown with database entries in the Paybands database table. For instance, if in Paybands I have (FTE, Contractor), and the current user I'm viewing is currently set to FTE, then when I click the dropdown while editing this user I want the dropdown to contain both FTE and Contractor. Currently, I'm only able to pull the value "FTE" for this user, because I don't know how to accomplish this in AngularJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned you need to have an endpoint on the server that will publish the list of paybands,  ie a controller named PaybandsController  in the controller you will need a Get action result that returns a list of Paybands from your database.  Your paybandResource should be glued to this and publish using the query function.  You would then hook up that vm.paybands to the UI as Yaser indicated.

```
function PersonnelEditCtrl(personnelResource, paybandResource, $filter) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.person = {};
    vm.message = '';
    vm.paybands = [];

    paybandResource.query(function(data) {
        vm.paybands = $filter('orderBy')(data, 'Name');
    });

 //.......
```

In the view

```
<select 
   ng-model="person.paybandId"                 
   ng-options="payband.name for payband in paybands track by payband.id">
</select>
```

Comment: Sure, I got the controller. On the ASP.NET/MVC/Web API side I'm all good and can expose all the data I need to the front-end. I'm still getting used to using AngularJS and wasn't sure how to combine both queries in a single AngularJS controller.

Comment: do you have the paybandResource created yet?

Comment: Creating that now...I'm just going to mimic what I had created for my personnelResource...

(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("common.services")
        .factory("personnelResource",
                ["$resource",
                 "appSettings",
                    personnelResource])

    function personnelResource($resource, appSettings) {
        return $resource(appSettings.serverPath + "/api/people/:id", null,
            {
                'update':{method:'PUT'}
            });
    }
}());

Comment: You're a life saver, John. This was exactly what I needed. For some reason $filter is undefined for me, but I switched it back to "vm.paybands = data;" and it worked fine.

Comment: You would have to bring in $filter.  I updated the code.  You could also do the order by on the server side or in the ui. see: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

Comment: thanks a lot braddah! That works perfect. Still getting the hang of things with Angular.

Comment: Hey John, do you know of a way that I can get the current person payband value to show up as a default and would you have any tips on why everything else in the form saves, but not the newly selected dropdown value? I can put this into another question and link to it if you want to get credit for answering another question, if you'd like.

Comment: I think you need to track by the id and display the text.  I updated the answer for more information check the docs  see: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a method to get all payband and then populate them in that select.

```
<select 
   ng-model="person.paybandId"                 
   ng-options="payband.name for payband in paybands">
</select>
```